# How remove characters minus (-) in middle or end in string c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I want delete one character minus `-` that the user press in a textbox. I validate that the user has not pressed the minus key twice with event `key_press`:

```
if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != '.') && (e.KeyChar != '-'))
{
     e.Handled = true;
}

 // only allow one minus -

if (e.KeyChar == '-' && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('-') > -1))
{
     e.Handled = true;
}
```

the problem is when the user presses the minus sign key in middle or end of the string.  For example:

1000.-00 <--- Invalid

2000.00- <--- Invalid

-1000.00 <--- valid

How can I ensure the minus sign is beginning the contents of the text box?

Comment: Why not just try to convert the value to a double instead?

Comment: Shouldn't you just warn the user that the input is invalid? Did the user mean 1000 or -1000? How can you decide which is which? "How can" == "Assume responsibility if you guess wrong"

Comment: Hi, i try convert to decimal but show error "Format exception" when user write one quantity 1000-.00

Comment: Anyway, Windows Forms has validator controls and events, including numeric validation and regular expressions, since version 1. Use *these* instead of handling key presses. Check [User Input Validation in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Check if the textbox contains anything before allowing the keypress

Answer (score 0):

use it like this

> declare a variable at class level like this int minusCount=0;

```
if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != '.') && (e.KeyChar != '-'))
{
     e.Handled = true;
}

 // only allow one minus -

//put condition if it is zero than only allow one minus sign
if (e.KeyChar == '-' && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('-') > -1) && minusCount==0)
{
     e.Handled = true;
     //over here increment that variable
     minusCount = minusCount+1;
     //for handling it in middle other than zero position
     if(textbox.Text.IndexOf("-")>1)
     {
        textbox.Text=textbox.Text.Replace("-","");
     }
}
```

Comment: problem with InstanceOf... this is in namespaces System.Object ?

Comment: sorry i want to write index of but instead write instanceof it was just a typo

Comment: thank's @rashfmnb in inspection watch IndexOf("-") > 0, 
because minus sign is the first

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.KeyChar == '-' && ((sender as TextBox).Text.Length > 1))
```

This allows only one dash at the beginning. Maybe you need to trim the Text first...

Comment: This will not work if the user would type a number, then hit [Home] button, and try making the value negative.

Comment: I commented so that you could change your answer if you'd like to make it more general.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your second `if` is that at the time when you do the check the `sender` (i.e. the `TextBox`) does not have the minus yet. You should construct the text with the minus first, then validate it to make a decision:

```
if (e.KeyChar == '-') {
    var tb = sender as TextBox;
    // Obtain the text after the modification
    var modifiedText = tb.Text.Insert(tb.SelectionStart, "-");
    // There will be at least one '-' in the text box - the one you just inserted.
    // Its position must be 0, otherwise the string is invalid:
    e.Handled = modifiedText.LastIndexOf("-") != 0;
}
```

Comment: but the event key_press not permit the "return modifiedText.LastIndexOf("-") != 0;" is void method

Comment: @RafaelSaavedra I meant to set `e.Handled` to a boolean result.

Comment: @RafaelSaavedra Did you give the change a try?